# Making images visible when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, onclick

I don't know much about Javascript but I would like to create a script that reveals a image on a page when a button is clicked.

**E.g.** there is a riddle, you can't solve it so you press the hint button and a hint appears. The same logic only with images instead.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I guess you'll have to learn Javascript then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After learning Javascript and jQuery it will be easy http://jsfiddle.net/mgs_jsfiddle/KYvJR/

```
<p>
   <a id="btnShow" href="#">show</a>
   <a id="btnHide" href="#">hide</a>
</p>
<p>
    <img id="img" src="doesnotexist" width="100px" height="100px" alt=""/>
</p>

$(function() {
    $("#btnShow").click(function() {
        $("#img").show();
    });
    $("#btnHide").click(function() {
        $("#img").hide();
    });
```

})

Answer (score 0):

simple solution for u.
you can place all images into this div or separate too..

```
<div id="image_holder" style="display:none">
//contains images
</div>

<input type="button" name="show" id="show" onclick="show_image()" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function show_image()
{
    document.getElementById("image_holder").style.display="block";  
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`this`](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/UBCAS/), this is help you

HTML

```
<img style='display:none' src='http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-xJEGhPWV5x8/UMA5xJBYFRI/AAAAAAAAKu0/R9gy-wLflEQ/s200/demo.jpg'/>
<input type="button" value='click Me'/>
```

JS

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function(){
$('img').show();
});
```